# Using a CSS Stylesheet with Javascript .innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp

If I have a javascript function that loads an error using

```
document.getElementById("ID").innerHTML = "This is your error";
```

And I want to stylize it say change the text to a different color, and put the error into a different position, how would I go about doing that? I've been looking around, and cannot find any information.

Comment: document.getElementById("ID").style.color="red"

Comment: Thanks, but I was told specifically to use CSS is there a way to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change an element's CSS class with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-css-class-with-javascript)

Comment: I never posted this before.

Comment: And having just looked it's not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As innerHTML suggests you can also add HTML. You could for instance add a span tag with a class that you style via CSS.

JS/CSS and HTML

```js
document.getElementById('error-message').innerHTML = "<span class='error'>my error</span>";
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div id="error-message"></div>
```

Comment: That is precisely what I am looking for thank you. One final question that relates, since I have a number of errors on my form, for example name.error, job. error and so on, is there a catch all I can use so that they would all fit under one css tag?

Answer (score 1):

Check this out , this answer should suffice to your needs:

```
document.getElementById("ID").innerHTML = "This is your error";
var sheet = document.createElement('style')
sheet.innerHTML = "div {color:red;overflow:hidden;}";
document.body.appendChild(sheet);
```

Add the below line to your span

```
#myspan{float:left;}
```

Working fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/0z971bsn/

As you mentioned in the comments , to check for errors you can refer to the answer to this question [How to get my forms' Javascript error function to cancel form submission and insert error message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22904637/how-to-get-my-forms-javascript-error-function-to-cancel-form-submission-and-ins)

Comment: OK, one quick question if I may.  What I have is in a span, at present it is underneath the field it is in reference too.  If I wanted the error to appear in line next to the field what would I do? I've tried floating it, but that just keeps it underneath, but to the right.

Comment: @JackParker ok , I edited my answer , check it out and let me know