# Add <span> to innerHTML with value

Tags: javascript, html, css

Based off this thread: [Using a CSS Stylesheet with Javascript .innerHTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28458208/using-a-css-stylesheet-with-javascript-innerhtml)

To stylize a innerHTML such as this:

```
document.getElementById("ID").innerHTML = "This is your error";
```

all you need to is this:

```
document.getElementById('error-message').innerHTML = "<span class='error'>my 
error</span>";
```

But what If I have a value? How would I apply the  tag to this:

```
document.getElementById('pText').innerHTML = "You clicked: " + value;
```

Comment: Does this do what you want? `document.getElementById('pText').innerHTML = "<span class='whatever'>You clicked: " + value + "</span>";`

Comment: Yes that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`innerHTML` is a string that's converted to / interpreted as HTML, so as long as you add the tags around your value, it'll work:

```
document.getElementById('pText').innerHTML = "<span>You clicked: " + value + "</span>";
```

Alternatively, you could add the span to your HTML directly, and set the innerHTML of the span to be `"You clicked :" + value` in your JS, which is a bit cleaner.

Comment: add some explanation instead of just a line of code

Comment: an explanation was added and this seemed to work. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As InnerHtml is a string here i append the value which is got from the click event it works.

```js
function pClicked(value){
 document.getElementById('pText').innerHTML = "<span class='error'>You Clicked "+value+"</span>";
}
```

```css
.error {
  color: red;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div id="pClicked" onClick="pClicked('pClicked Div')">Click here</div>

<div id="pText"></div>
```

Comment: Is this is the way that you want to work? Is this is the output you need?